# How to get last inserted record in MySql which does not have 'id' column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For the tables having 'id' column , we can use select last_insert_id() to retrieve the id of last inserted row, but in my table  I am not using 'id' column. So how do I retrieve the last row?

The table structure is:

```
uuid varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
version bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
criteria_json text,
date_created varchar(30) NOT NULL
```

Comment: if you have `datetime` column on insert you can get most recent. Or share your table structure to look further.

Comment: `uuid` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL , `version` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `criteria_json` text,`date_created` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

Comment: You can use `date_created ` as an identifier but if there is multiple insert happens in same sec then you have difficult, it's better you have explicit AI id.

Comment: Since you don't have `id` column could you please explain why you need `last_insert_id`?

Comment: In a sql table there is no concept of ordering, other than that which is explicitly defined in columns. So it can't be done in any meaningful reliable way unless you add a suitable column, which you do NOT have.

Answer (score 0):

The function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the value of the `AUTOINCREMENT` column of the last row inserted in this session. Other simultaneous sessions don't affect this value.

Since you don't seem to have an `AUTOINCREMENT` column it won't return anything for this table. See the [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change `date_created`  to timestamp ( `DATETIME(6)` ) which will record milliseconds, use below query,

```
select * from yourtable order by date_created  desc limit 1
```

Comment: this does not seems to be working for multiple inserts at a time.

Comment: try creating column with  DATETIME(6)